# Is destroyDrawingCache() of view expensive operation?

Tags: android, view

Is destroyDrawingCache() expensive operation ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `buildDrawingCache()` manually without calling `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)`, you should cleanup the cache by calling `destroyDrawingCache()` afterwards.

You should avoid calling this method when hardware acceleration is enabled. If you do not need the drawing cache bitmap, calling this method will increase memory usage and cause the view to be rendered in software once, thus negatively impacting performance.